# How do I make evil-search-forward / evil-search-backward use fuzzy search?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

I'd like to search in buffer with the same fuzzy style that turns the search string into a regexp that splits characters and joins them with `.*`, like in Helm command search.

Is there a way to do this for `evil-search-forward` and `evil-search-backward` in Spacemacs?

Comment: These are implemented in terms of isearch, so if you find something working for that, it shouldn't be hard to change Evil to do the same thing.

Comment: Does it have to be done by `evil-search-forward`? Have you tried `helm-swoop`? (I'm not entirely sure that does exactly fuzzy search, because I use ivy instead of helm)  `SPC h d f helm-swoop` to see what key sequence that's bound to (`SPC s s`, I'm guessing? With `ivy` selected, that runs `swiper` -- in fact so did `C-s` I think, before I rebound that).

Comment: I didn't know about `helm-swoop`, but yes, it is bound to `SPC s s` (very convenient). It doesn't come with fuzzy find by default, but it does have an option `(setq helm-swoop-use-fuzzy-match t)`, so that solved it for me. I don't know if I should leave the question open in case someone wants the specific answer, but if you post yours I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Leaning on the built-in isearch, the custom variable `search-whitespace-regexp` and these key bindings works pretty well for me.

```
(custom-set-variables '(search-whitespace-regexp ".*"))
(evil-define-key '(normal) 'global "/" (lambda () (interactive) (isearch-forward)))
(evil-define-key '(normal) 'global "?" (lambda () (interactive) (isearch-backward)))
(evil-define-key '(normal) 'global "n" (lambda () (interactive) (isearch-repeat-forward)))
(evil-define-key '(normal) 'global "N" (lambda () (interactive) (isearch-repeat-backward)))
```

Or you can use swiper (which I think does fuzzy matching by default) but it's pretty slow and I don't need the preview feature. But it worked fine for me in the past.

Note: In the above example, "n" and "N" don't behave exactly like evil mode since they always go in the same direction every time. You can easily configure that though.